# Setting Context-Root with Glassfish Application Server

Tags: glassfish

I have a EJB WEB Application with an Glassfish Application-Server.
Now i want the Context-Root like this "/". 
My current URL is "http://localhost:8080/Make"
but i want this one :"http://localhost:8080" without the "Make" as my Application Name currently is. But hen i deploy it and tip "http://localhost:8080" i got the "Server is running" page from glassfish
So i trie to figure out what i can do. I have create a glassfish-web.xml in my WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish   Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-  web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
<context-root>/</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Nothing happens. Than i have create a sun-web.xml in the same folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC 
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN"   
 "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
<context-root>/path/to/our/App</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

Also i hvae trie with a glassfish-application.xml and application.xml.
So what must i do to take this effect?

PS: this is my web.xml and i deploy as EAR file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<display-name>Make</display-name>
<mime-mapping>
<extension>xhtml</extension>
<mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>anmeldung.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
 <error-page>
 <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
<location>/anmeldung.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

EDIT: The application.xml in the WEB-INF Folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
<application-name>Make</application-name>
<display-name>Make</display-name>
<module>
<web>
  <web-uri>Make.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
</web>
 </module>
<module>
  <ejb>makeITown.jar</ejb>
</module>
<library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Comment: Exactly the same setup is working here...do you maybe have the `maven-ear-plugin` in your `pom.xml`? This could overwrite the application.xml with a generated one.

Comment: Dosen't use Maven

Comment: This is really strange. I have the same setup here and tried it with your `web.xml` and it works....

Comment: What's your Port? I have choose 4888 not the 80*

Comment: Your URLs in the question show port 8080 but that shouldn't matter. Maybe the problem is how you deploy the application. Do you use Ant for deploying?

Comment: No i use the Glassfish Administration Console

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to define context-root for an `ejb module` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the context root to `/` is not enough to be able to access your web app only by typing `http://yourdomain.org` because Glassfish will display the "Your server is running" message found in index.html`.

To get your app launch. set the `Default Web Module` drop down found in `Configuration | server-config | Virtual Servers | server` (in the Web console) to the name of your web app.

Comment: How Can i achieve the same in payara micro?

Comment: Is it possible to define context-root for an `ejb module` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `glassfish-web.xml` you posted seems to be ok.

If you deploy you application as EAR, you may need and application.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <application-name>something</application-name>
  <display-name>something</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>your_webapplication.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>your_ejb_services.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

This is just a template example. You can also have multiple web-modules and ejb-modules.

If you deploy via the Glassfish Admin UI you can set the context root when deploying:

[image: deploy application to glassfish]

If you use asadmin for deploying you can set the context root like this:

```
asadmin deploy --name something --contextroot / /path/of/your/war.war
```

Comment: Ok, then we need more information about your setup. If you have one, add your web.xml to the question. Do you deploy as EAR or as WAR?

Comment: @unwichtig - you made my day :) The Problem was that i didn'T create the META-INF Folder in the .EAR file. Now it works! THX

Comment: Is it possible to define context-root for an `ejb module` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not late I have struggled with the same problem. For a while now and no matter what I tried the server spit out the default your `your server is running page`.
What needs to be done to be able to visit `example.com` without having to enter `example.com/example` where example is the `contextroot` defined in your `glassfish-web.xml` is ip tables rerouting and can be accomplished as follows.

### Assuming you are on ubuntu server 20.04LTS execute below commands as root

root@example.com:~$

```
root@example.com:~$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
root@example.com:~$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
root@example.com:~$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
root@example.com:~$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8181
```

### You have to make this permanent:

```
root@example.com:~$ iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
root@example.com:~$ iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

### And call during startup,

```
root@example.com:~$ vi /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
```

### Copy and paste below commands into the iptablesload file opened by `vi`
above

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

### Don't forget to make iptablesload executable with

```
root@example.com:~$ chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload!
```